# formulate an expression meaning "oversimplification approach"

Tags: phrase-request

What would be the appropriate expression to define a "oversimplification approach"?

Comment: The phrase would mean an approach that oversimplifies things *in order to achieve something*. To oversimplify means to ignore some of the facts while making the problem easier to understand (or do). Approach is a way of doing or thinking about something.

Answer (score 1):

It would be an *oversimplified* (made too simple) *approach.*

Talking of the possible approaches *(as ideas or actions intended to deal with a problem or situation),* they may also be *balanced, common-sense, no-nonsense, positive, practical, pragmatic, problem-solving, rational, sensible, straightforward, useful* and whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could say something such as "get down to brass tacks" or just say "simply," "bluntly," "basically," or something like that.